# Typescript: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'boolean'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of strings representing numbers, and I want to be able to see how many times a certain string repeats on my array:

```
const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '2', '9', '5', '2'. '4', '8'];
const searchForValue = '2';
const timesAppeared = numbers.reduce(
      (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + (currentValue === searchForValue),
      0
);
```

However, the operation inside my reduce function gives me the following error:

`Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'boolean'.`

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Coerce the condition to a number as you would in JavaScript?

Comment: as @kelly indicates, Typescript just wants you to explicitly coerce to a valid type for the operation `(previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + Number(currentValue === searchForValue),` (which is the point of a type system, to flag type mismatches, especially given javascripts type fluidity)

Comment: Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is more straightforward, even if a bit more expensive. `timesAppeared.filter(c => c === searchForValue).length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to keep the code relatively the same, just added the Number cast/constructor.

```
const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '2', '9', '5', '2', '4', '8'];
const searchForValue = '2';
const timesAppeared = numbers.reduce(
      (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + Number(currentValue === searchForValue),
      0
);
```

Typescript loves type consistency! Before your code was trying to add a boolean result to a number which isn't possible (e.g. 1 + false). All we did here was convert that boolean result to a number. However I would recommend learning how the ternary operation in Alexander Mills' answer works.

Answer (score 5):

try this instead

```
const timesAppeared = numbers.reduce(
      (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + (currentValue === searchForValue ? 1 : 0),
      0
);
```

now the ternary operator returns a Number, before you were creating a Boolean.

Comment: This will look way cooler using the `Number` constructor function `(previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + Number(currentValue === searchForValue)` , as suggested by pilchard 

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
searchForValue ='2';
timesAppeared = 0
for (let index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
    if(searchForValue==numbers[index]){
        timesAppeared=timesAppeared+1;
    }
    console.log(timesAppeared);
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to stop using `reduce`. This is a suggestion which should be a comment.